# Downloading a file through web application [best practice]

Tags: javascript

I am new with web application development.  I have a code that lets you download a file after passing a basic authentication.  It is working so far but I am not sure if this is the correct solution in achieving this solution.  Or is there a drawback using this solution?

The "download" processing is being handled on a javascript using this code.

```
function downloadFile() {
var s = queryString("fn");
var f = "/web/et/" + s;

if (s.length > 1) {
    window.open(f, "Download");
}
}

function queryString(parameter) {
var loc = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
var param_value = false;
var params = loc.split("&");
for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    param_name = params[i].substring(0, params[i].indexOf('='));
    if (param_name == parameter) {
        param_value = params[i].substring(params[i].indexOf('=') + 1)
    }
}
if (param_value) {
    return param_value;
}
else {
    return ""; //Here determine return if no parameter is found
}
}
```

@EDIT:

Sorry if I forgot to include the question, my question is, Is there a drawback on using this kind of solution? (pertains to downloading a file using javascript).  Or is there a better solution for downloading a file aside from using a javascript?

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working properly? What's the purpose of this code?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the main post again.

Comment: You are *not* downloading a file using Javascript. You are simply opening a new window which URL happens to be a file, based on the current URL being executed. Is something not working properly?

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, it is working properly, but my question is, is my solution an appropriate one?

Comment: We can't answer that for you. Presumably you chose that solution because it seemed appropriate for your situation. I don't understand *why* you are doing what you are doing in your javascript, but I have *no basis for judging it* at all, because I'm not the one writing your application. Do you have a *specific* question about some *particular* code you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

I would handle any authentication on the server side b/c it is too easy to manipulate the (plainly) visible JS source.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Updated.  Sorry I forgot to include my question.